# Plastic nipple on fuel tank busted, as well as plastic connector on fuel line

Tags: dodge, fuel-tank, caravan

2000 Dodge Caravan 2.4L. Purchased on Sunday because it wouldn't start, because why would I purchase a working vehicle?

Anyway, the photos are attached.

[image: Fuel line connector busted]
[image: Connector on tank busted]

What do I do, folks?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Exactly. Why purchase a working vehicle? Those cost money.  One thing I've learned is the scarce thing in modern life isn't money or parts, but interest/giving a darn.  People will just get rid of things with minor defects because it's not worth their TROUBLE.

Comment: Totally @Harper-ReinstateMonica. I'm by no means a mechanic and actually work in IT and have nothing to do with automotive. However, I like diagnosing and fixing things. Plus saving some dough? This is technically a minor defect because at worst you would have to replace the tank. Cosmetically, it is pretty sound. The owner said she really didn't want to scrap it but was going to if it didn't sell.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to repair it (ie: glue it), but it probably wouldn't hold for too long. Your best bet is to go to a You-Pull-It wrecking yard and find a replacement.

Comment: Was trying to hurry back here.

Comment: Need to drop the tank, remove fuel pump, and get the tank nipple out. Then push in a new one through the bottom. Same with the line one I'm hoping, just pull out and replace.

Comment: You're right about glue, I'm not sure there's much that could survive the pressure for long. It would be a one-time shaky fix.

Comment: @Ulvdet - I didn't realize it was the fuel hat ... should have realized. Still, doesn't change my answer.